# Retrieve FlexiPage layout for default Opportunity record type for current user

Tags: lightning, opportunity, profile, flexipages, lightning-action-override

#### Question

For the current user, how do you programmatically retrieve the FlexiPage layout (i.e. fields) for the default Opportunity record type?

#### What I've Tried

Since, the FlexiPage layout potentially depends on the user's profile and the app (e.g. Sales), my current approach is to retrieve the app's `ActionOverride` and `ProfileActionOverride` lists.

High Level Steps

1. Get current user's profile: `SELECT FullName FROM Profile WHERE Id = '<profile_id>'`
2. Get all Opportunity FlexiPages: `SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM FlexiPage Where EntityDefinitionId = 'Opportunity'`
3. Get Sales app `Metadata`: `SELECT Metadata FROM CustomApplication WHERE Label = 'Sales'`
4. Check Sales app `ActionOverride` list from `Metadata` and see if there is a FlexiPage associated with Opportunity.
5. Check Sales app `ProfileActionOverride` list from `Metadata` and see if there is a FlexiPage associated with Opportunity and user's profile.
6. Get Opportunity FlexiPage from `ActionOverride` or `ProfileActionOverride` and retrieve FlexiPage layout.

#### Issue

Sometimes, the Sales app `Metadata` contains an empty list for `ActionOverride` and `ProfileActionOverride`. In this scenario, how do you retrieve the FlexiPage layout (i.e. fields) for the default Opportunity record type?

Comment: so the lightning page is activated by app+profile but applies to all recordtypes? Do you have recordtypes defined on Opportunity?

Comment: For some users, the Lightning page is assigned by app, profile, and record type. For other users, the Lightning page is NOT assigned by app, profile, or record type -- hence empty `ActionOverride` and `ProfileActionOverride` lists. There could be multiple record types defined for an Opportunity, but the default record type is used to retrieve the Lightning page layout.

Comment: Maybe the flexipage "layout" is derived at run time from the `Layout` metadataType that is assigned to the default record type